# MongoDB $lookup for embedded collections

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have 2 collections:

**UserCollection :**

```
[
   {
      "_id" : ObjectId("3a9ccf7de6348936d88b3601"),
      "first_name" : "John",
   },
   {
       "_id" : ObjectId("3a9ccf7de6348936d88b3602"),
       "first_name" : "Jane",
   }
]
```

**CommentCollection (with embedded ReplyCollection) :**

```
[
   {
      "_id" : ObjectId("3a9ccf7de6348936d88b3601"),
      "user_id": ObjectId("3a9ccf7de6348936d88b3601"),
      "body" : "Hello World",
      "replies":
      [
          {
             "_id" : ObjectId("3a9ccf7de6348936d88b3441"),
             "user_id": ObjectId("3a9ccf7de6348936d88b3601"),
             "body" : "World said, Hello Back", 
          }
      ]
   },
   {
       "_id" : ObjectId("3a9ccf7de6348936d88b3602"),
       "user_id": ObjectId("3a9ccf7de6348936d88b3601"),
       "body" : "Hello Stack",
       "replies":
       [
          {
             "_id" : ObjectId("3a9ccf7de6348936d88b3602"),
             "body" : "Stack said Overflow",
             "user_id": ObjectId("3a9ccf7de6348936d88b3601"),
          }
       ]
   }
]
```

**Query to join Comments & Users :**

```
db.comments.aggregate([
   { "$lookup": {
     "from": "Users",
     "localField": "user_id",
     "foreignField": "_id",
     "as": "user" } 
   },
   {"$unwind": "$user"}
]);
```

**Behaviour**: comments and user table were joined as expected.

**Question**: Is it possible to join also the reply-user relation within the same query?

Thx in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can do that using [uncorrelated-subquery](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/index.html#uncorrelated-subquery) in `$lookup` :

```
db.comments.aggregate([
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "Users",
      let: {
        repliesUserId: "$replies.user_id",
        userId: "$user_id"
      },
      pipeline: [
        {
          $match: {
            $expr: {
              $or: [
                { $eq: ["$_id", "$$userId"] },
                { $in: ["$_id", "$$repliesUserId"] }
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      as: "user"
    }
  }
]);
```

**Test :** [MongoDB-Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/s8sr2A2jtuJ)

Comment: almost on, the result is an array containing all users who postet any replies but not the user object inside the reply object

Comment: @creality: I would suggest to do it in code, it would be easy with code & I tried & it's becoming more complex & wouldn't be recommended on huge datasets..

Comment: true. Thinking about to store the replies in the same collection as the comments and not as a sub-document. This makes things a lot easier...

Comment: @creality : That shouldn't be the case everytime, your docs might go bigger in size if  `replies` array is much bigger. But in general you could that if your `Users` collection has only two fields `first_name &_id` as given above & also your applicate is flexible to write `first_name` every time to `comments` collection & also security matter(You might not want to expose `first_name` every time when you retrieve comments data). So check all these & think thru I would with current situation you're pretty go & do some minor coding to get what you need (In general if DB can't offload it to code)

Comment: jap thats true. But I testet some cases and I figured out that in general it is not a good idea to store replies, votes and so on in the comment document. Mongo has a 16MB limitation on each object and objects grow quickly. For example I added 100.000 likes and voila - 16MB raised. I came up splitting the structure.